# Parsing string to see if it can be cast to a float

Tags: python, validation, floating-point

Part of my homework assignment is to write a function that will parse a string such as `'-.4e-4'` and identify any problems that would prevent it from being cast to a float. For example, in `'10e4.5'` I would need to detect the decimal in the exponent and provide a relevant error message.

I have attempted many things. The first and, of course, most basic is the try: except:. Attempt to cast it to a float and let Python do the heavy lifting. However, as far as I can see, the errors it can return are not descriptive enough for this assignment.

The second thing I tried was to normalize the string, replacing all digits with n, signs with s, decimals with d, exponents with e (the maketrans function from C made this very fast). Then, I cut down any repeated n's to a single n. I made a list of all valid float formats and checked if the normalized string was in that list. AKA, I white-listed it. It worked perfectly and rather time-efficiently, but again, no error checking. That code is posted below.

```
import string,time
check_float_trans = string.maketrans("nsd0123456789-+.","???nnnnnnnnnnssd")
check_float_valids = 'n sn sndn ndn ndnen dn sdn sdnen sdnesn dnesn dnen nen nesn snesn sn snen sndnen sndnesn ndnesn'.split()
def check_float( test ):
    """Check if string <test> could be cast as a float, returns boolean."""
    test = test.translate(check_float_trans)
    test = ''.join([a for a,b in zip(test, ' '+test) if a != b])
    return test in check_float_valids
```

I was hoping someone here could give me some pointers. I don't want this handed to me, but I am relatively stuck. I tried guardian-coding it, trying to identify reasons why the string might not be castable as a float, but I could never put up enough walls to ensure that no bad strings got a false positive.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `regular expression`

Comment: We aren't allowed to use regular expressions on this one, either. I know. Very stringent rules. Although I did find a Python module that had exactly the regex I needed... I wish...

Comment: That's very frustrating (and in my opinion, a poorly written assignment). It might make this question too localized, though. Why don't you just have a series of `if/else` statements in the except clause?

Comment: What probably would help in suggesting a solution is a bit more information on what part of your programming course you are in. Most courses base assignments on a search for a particular solution that would use the information/techniques you were just taught.

Comment: Well, I actually have the function the teacher wanted us to write, but found flaws in it. Quite a few flaws. I could post that if it would help, but essentially, it would look for a sign, loop through to the decimal, loop through to the exponent, look for another sign... It failed for alot of floats he probably didn't account for. Once I gave him my solution (posted above), he was surprised, and asked me to make a version which does what I described above; informs the user WHY the float isn't valid. So, I'm trying. I just need a few more ideas to spark the creative juices in me, mainly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do... (also this is untested)

```
def isValid(expression):

    if 'e' in expression:
        number, exponent = expression.split('e')
    else:
        print "not a valid format, no 'e' in expression"
        return False

    # a bunch of other if statments here to check for
    #certain conditions like '.' in the exponent component

    return float(number) ** float(exponent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print isValid('-.4e-4')
    print isValid('10e4.5')
```